# VTD-xml remove the remaining line after calling remove() on an VTDNav

Tags: xml, vtd-xml

It is my  understanding that this was a known issue to be fixed in later releases of VTD-XML .  From my current observation , this has not been fixed yet.  Is there a specific well designed work-around for this ?

The new line left after removing content is really annoying because it corrupts the diff of a file from version x to version x1.

Comment: a new method called expandWhitespace is added in 2.12 that you can call to remove white spaces in this use case... it is already in the cvs repository that you can check out... the basic usage is call vn.expandWhitespace(vn.getContentFragment()) this returns a long which you then remove with XMLModifier... check out vtdNav.java from cvs if you can...

Comment: this is a permanent fix, not a work around fyi...

Comment: :(  So I checked out the file from the cvs repository and although the issue is no longer present ,  I am faced with the deleted content begins right after the element before the  deleted content.  any ideas?

Comment: @ vtd-xml-author :(  So I checked out the file from the cvs repository and although the issue is no longer present ,  I am faced with the deleted content begins right after the element before the  deleted content.  any ideas?_
<a>
</a>
<b>
</b>
<c>
</c>

after b is removed becomes

<a>
</a><c>
</c>

Comment: sorry I fail to see how is that not what you wanted? why is that a problem?

Comment: Hi   the initial document has the following format .  <a></a>line break<b></b>line break<c></c>. After deleting b i expect <a></a>line break <c></c>  but what I have with the fix is  <a></a><c></c> . the line break is gone which corrupts my initial format. How can I address that ?

Comment: that particular function either leaves white spaces as is or remove all white spaces... have you thought of that, instead of removing the content, you replace the content with line break? in other words, use update method call instead of remove method?

Answer (score 0):

A new method called expandWhitespace is added in 2.12 that you can call to remove white spaces in this use case... it is already in the cvs repository that you can check out... the basic usage is call `vn.expandWhitespace(vn.getContentFragment())` this returns a long which you then remove with XMLModifier... check out vtdNav.java from cvs if you can...

Comment: You pretty much re-type your previous answer . I am not sure if my last comment was misunderstood.

Comment: You pretty much re-typed your previous answer . I am not sure if my last comment was misunderstood. I checked-out the file VTDNav and made the call vn.expandwhitespace(vn.getContentFragment()) . Although that solved the problem of a new line left after removing the error , I am left with another issue . The issue that I am hitting now is that the line break  between the preceding element and the following element is gone .  How do I solve that .

Comment: You want to be able to pick and choose which white space to keep and which ones to remove?